# Trouble in using 'pattern=' in HTML

Tags: html, regex, validation

Good day guys!

I am having trouble in using pattern input attributes without using css or javascript.

this is the code that I'm using so far for username:

Username
must consist of 4 to 15 characters only

```html
pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_]|.{4,15}"
```

The problem is that the input still accepting special characters like "*"

How to trap these special characters?

Comment: *Username must consist of 4 to 15 characters only* - Then just use `pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,15}"` or even `pattern="\w{4,15}"`, `|.` is spoiling all that as `.` matches *any character but a newline*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Username must consist of 4 to 15 characters only*

Then just use `pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,15}"` or even `pattern="\w{4,15}"` (because `[A-Za-z0-9_]` = `\w` in JS).

The `|.` is ruining the pattern as `.` matches *any character but a newline*. `[A-Za-z0-9_]|.{4,15}` matches one word character string or a string containing *any*, character 4 to 15 occurrences.

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="\w{4,15}" title="4 to 15 word characters are only allowed!"/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: it works! but I have one problem.. the placeholder on my text turns red when I apply the css.. is there a way to disable the css first until the user has an input then validate it? because the design and the css is not good combination. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ZJk4qan.png

Comment: I think you can remove that CSS - it is only for testing purposes (I just used it for a demo). HTML5 validation error will appear once you click submit.

Comment: how about phone numbers? In my opinion correct me if I'm wrong this will need a database to check if the first 4-5 digit number is valid: Like here in the Philippines our country code is 63 and these are some valid phone number we use: 0906 or 63906, 0917 or 63917 etc. is this possible in pattern=""?

Comment: Sorry, that does not sound pertinent to the current question. There are tons of phone validation questions here, please check.